# How to copy the elements of the copied element into an array without looping through it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy, element, nodes

Can you please tell me how to copy elements to an array without going through them again through `getElementsByTagName("*")`, and so that they refer to the copied element?

HTML:

```
<div id="id1"><p id="p1">1</p><p id="p2">2</p></div>
```

JS:

```
const el = document.getElementById("id1");
const arr = [];
if(el)
for (const element of el.getElementsByTagName("*")) {
  if(element.textContent === "1") arr.push(element)
}
const cloneEl = el?.cloneNode(true);
function arrCloneWithRelationToCloneEl(arr , cloneEl){
...
return arrClone;
}
```

Result:

```
arrClone = [p#p1]
```

from cloneEl.

Can this be done at all without iterating over the nodes of the cloned element, but somehow by id in childNodes or by creating a virtual DOM to do it? Maybe there is some special function for copying, only to not have to loop every time an object is cloned.

I will be very grateful for the answer!

I tried to do it through creating path in childNodes array. Something like this array `[0,0]` in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using `document.getElementById` doesn't clone the node. It gets the element as an object of the DOM API.

For your use case by getting a child element with a specific `.textContent`, there isn't any function you can use to get the element. However, you can shorten your code by a lot by converting `el.getElementsByTagName("*")`  into an array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), then using `.filter()` to only get sub-elements with the specified `.textContent`. To handle `el` being `null`, you can use a quick ternary expression to return an empty array if the element doesn't exist:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('id1');
const arr = el ? [...el.getElementsByTagName("*")].filter(x => x.textContent == '1') : [];

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <p id="p1">1</p>
  <p id="p2">2</p>
</div>
```

However, if you're instead looking for an element with a certain attribute, class, or anything else that can be searched for with a CSS selector, then you can use `el.querySelectorAll` and once again use spread syntax to convert to an array:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('id1');
const arr = el ? [...el.querySelectorAll('[x-attribute="1"]')] : [];

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <p id="p1" x-attribute="1">First element</p>
  <p id="p2" x-attribute="2">Second element</p>
</div>
```

Comment: children != getElementsByTagName("*")

Comment: @TelevisionMaster1 Sorry, in your question you only provided an example where `el.children` was needed, however, my answer still works if you use `el.getElementsByTagName("*")` instead of `el.children`. I've edited my answer to use `el.getElementsByTagName("*")` instead.